# AWS Gateway proxy to an existing WebSocket server

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

thank you for reading this question.

what is the way to use AWS API Gateway to proxy communication to a WebSocket server running on EC2?

I tried HTTP/REST and WebSocket with no success.

thank you

Comment: Could you find any solution?

Comment: I used the load balancer to do that. to move WebSocket to the right service

Answer (score 0):

To integrate API Gateway with a server, the server should be Http server(request/response) and not web-socket server.
[Check this post. noninertialframe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70679996/aws-api-gateway-websocket-api-how-to-use-it-with-react-nodejs-native-websoc#:%7E:text=As%20a%20side,invoked%20upon%20connection.:%7E:text=As%20a%20side,invoked%20upon%20connection.)

> If you need to **run your own backend, do not use AWS API Gateway** WebSocket API because there is no need to. You can use AWS ALB instead.
> If you don't have to run your own backend and if the features are not too complex, use AWS Lambda Integration with WebSocket API and take the real-time feature serverless.
> If you need to use API Gateway, you can set up the HTTP endpoints on your Node.js backend, and integrate it to the WebSocket API $connect integration. Then, the HTTP endpoint that you integrated will be invoked upon connection

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34992168)

Comment: The essential parts of the answer has been added @RobinaMirbahar

Comment: You are giving answer from someone post kindly answer yourself

Comment: @RobinaMirbahar I found that noninertialframe had answered the same question but in a different post. So I just wanted to link it here. I just couldn't understand your problem. Kindly elaborate. (Also I have added my interpretation)